# Remove only 1 Item from inventory

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to remove only 1 item, or the hold item stack when I click on it with opened inventory, but, the method: `player.getInventory().remove(item)`, remove all similar items in inventory, how can I remove only 1 item, or 1 `ItemStack`?

Comment: Please show your code, and explain what type `player.getInventory()` returns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bukkit remove item from inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870568/bukkit-remove-item-from-inventory)

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of information, this is my best guess:

```
player.getInventory().remove(item)
```

This method probably removes all the items in the inventory that when compared to the one passed as argument using the equals() method, return true.

So, you could try two things:

1. Implement or change the equals method in the class of the item argument
2. Set different attribute values in the item instance so that the equals() no longer returns true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clear` method:

```java
void clear​(int index)

Clears out a particular slot in the index.

Parameters:
    index - The index to empty.
```

Use it as follows:

```java
// removes just a first stack of golden apples

int firstGoldenAppleIndex = player.getInventory().first(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
bool foundGoldenApple = firstGoldenAppleIndex != -1;

if (foundGoldenApple) {
  player.getInventory().clear(firstGoldenAppleIndex);
}
```